# Problems in highlighting rows in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to highlight the active row of recyclerview which is playing in my music player.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.txt1.setText(data.get(i).get("text1").toString());
        viewHolder.txt2.setText(data.get(i).get("text2").toString());

        try{
            if(data.get(i).get("text1").toString().equals("Alan Walker - Alone")){
             viewHolder.txt1.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.activeText));

            }
        }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

In the following example data is just a list of songs. I am just trying to select "Alan Walker - Alone" but the problem is

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iNzR.jpg)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXeeM.jpg)

some other rows are highlighted too.. any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView recycles old items to create new items. So whenever you use an `if` condition in `onBindViewHolder()`, you must also use an `else`.

So your code becomes like this:

```
if(data.get(i).get("text1").toString().equals("Alan Walker - Alone")){
    viewHolder.txt1.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.activeText));
} else {
    viewHolder.txt1.setTextColor(/*Default text color*/);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me... can you explain why it worked with else statement??

Comment: As I said, RecyclerView recycles old items, and creates new items out of them when inflating. So when these views are redrawn, they are set with a wrong `textColor`